# Paperclip or Google Cloud Storage issue when renaming paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, google-cloud-storage, image-uploading

I've a Rails app with Paperclip and I use Google Cloud Storage. So far so good.

To avoid having both development and production using the same storage, I decided to change the default Paperclip path to another based based on the environment. This way every env has his own directory. Then I consistently moved the old images from the default Paperclip path to the new ones.

The problem is that now old images give a 404, whereas any new image I upload works properly. Is there any way to fix that?

Here it's the previous settings:

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :fog,
    fog_public: true,
    fog_directory: 'myapp-01',
    fog_credentials: {
      google_storage_access_key_id: ENV['GOOGLE_STORAGE_ID'],
      google_storage_secret_access_key: ENV['GOOGLE_STORAGE_SECRET'],
      provider: 'Google'
    }
  }
}
```

I override the default using the following settings:

```
    path: ":rails_env/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename",
    url:  "/:rails_root/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"
```

My guess is that it's not sufficient to update Paperclip config with the new path and move all images to the new directory. You need also to update the old records... 
If you wonder, the old records point to `root/images/?123456789`.

Comment: How about you show us some code? What are the production/development settings? Your `has_attached_file`, just like you copy images are you syncing the DB too? If so, how? I'm also not sure what you mean by "old images give a 404", shouldn't you be using the new path instead?

Comment: My guess is that Google doesn't let me see the image. Maybe some permission setting that got lost? Honestly that `url` setting doesn't really work as in new images the `src` has the default Google url of the bucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is right. Changing the config is not enough, you need to move the files. This, is better left for a rake task or background job. I have some code for **S3**, but it  should give you an idea of how to implement it for Google:

```
  def old_key(image, file_name_field)
    # Previous `:path`: '/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename'
    klass = self.class.to_s.pluralize.downcase
    attachment = image.pluralize
    "#{klass}/#{attachment}/#{id}/original/#{send(file_name_field)}"
  end

  def re_path(image)
    file_name_field = "#{image}_file_name"
    return if send(file_name_field).blank?

    old_object = bucket.object(old_key(image, file_name_field))
    return unless old_object.exists?

    Rails.logger.warn "Re-saving image attachment #{self.class}/#{id}"
    send "#{image}=", URI.parse(old_object.public_url)
    save
  end
```

I'm basically building the old path using my own interpolation, finding the object in S3 (hence key/object lingo) and re-download every image from S3. Be careful with this, since you might incur in extra cost for downloading rather than just moving, if that's someone Google allows.

Then I just called this method on every image for every object:

```
Object.each do { |o| o.re_path(:logo); o.re_path(:background); }
```

Comment: Thank you @Leito, I will implement the rake task following your suggestion and I'll let you know.

Comment: Hi @Leito, I'm back on this issue that I left aside for a while. I tried these methods but I cannot understand it completely. What is 'bucket'? I get `undefined local variable or method 'bucket'`.

Comment: In my code, `bucket` an instance of Aws::S3::Bucket.new, pointing to the right bucket. Ultimately I'm interested in knowing if the object exists and getting its URL.

Comment: Understood. I'm trying to get my head around this, but it's a bit overkill to do. I've seen [this page](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Changing-attachment-%3Apath) in the wiki and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/121onto/acc588b859893ddacebf) which uses a migration, but it's pretty hard to understand and set it up... so depressing. Wish it wouldn't be so complex.

Comment: As in any problem in CS, abstract the complexities out and it becomes simple (both the wiki article and my code matches at that point): (1) if image_file_name field is blank, do nothing; (2) if the file doesn't exists*, do nothing: (3) read* the file contents and save it through `.image=` and `.save`.

Both the exists? and reading the file change based on where you stored them. I used S3 methods, the wiki uses the file system methods, you need to use Google Cloud Storage methods.